# Instantiating and making a game object from a .FBX file gives error of persistent object

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, gameobject, fbx

I am a newcomer to programming and `Unity`, so may be i have a simple qustion but i am stuck in it.

i have a `. FBX` file imported to `Unity`. I have to get all the job done only in `editor`, by scripts. i am trying to make a `prefab` from it, and make a `GameObject`. All the ways i am trying, are giving errors- like the object is `null`( while i have it in the folders) or  Can't save `persistent object` as a `Prefab` `asset`.
Any ideas how can i get the wrong point?
here is the ways i tried.

```
GameObject objToPrefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Resources/"  + "/wolf.fbx", 
   typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
 PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab("Assets/Resource/" +   "/"  + ".prefab", objToPrefab);
```

or this one

```
 var obj = GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load(string.Format("fbx/{0}/{0}_model", name))) as GameObject;

   GameObject obj = GameObject.Instantiate(AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Models/121212",   GetAsset("Assets/Models/121212").GetType() )) as GameObject;
```

or

> ```
>     var MyObj = Resources.Load("wolf") as GameObject;
>     GameObject.Instantiate(MyObj);
> ```

Answer (score -1):

ok, how i figured out

```
 var myVector = new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  
    var obj = GameObject.Instantiate(Resources.Load("Wolf"), myVector, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```